# ModuleNotFoundError when trying to run executable created with setuptools

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

This is my project structure

```
/Users/tom/PycharmProjects/foo
├── __init__.py
├── foo
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── app.py
│   └── run.py
└── setup.py
```

app.py:

```
def hello_world():
    print("Hello world")
```

run.py:

```
from foo.app import hello_world

def main():
    hello_world()
```

setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='foo',
    version='0.0.1',
    packages=find_packages(),
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'foo=foo.run:main',
        ]
    }
)
```

After using pip to install I have the following folder structure:

```
/Users/tom/Desktop/foo/
├── bin
│   └── foo
├── foo
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── app.py
│   └── run.py
└── foo-0.0.1.dist-info
    ├── INSTALLER
    ├── METADATA
    ├── RECORD
    ├── REQUESTED
    ├── WHEEL
    ├── direct_url.json
    ├── entry_points.txt
    └── top_level.txt
```

When running the executable foo in /bin I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tom/Desktop/foo/bin/foo", line 5, in <module>
    from foo.run import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foo'
```

How can I make the executable work **without** having to activate a virtual environment and run it from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by changing the import statement in run.py to:

```
from app import hello_world
```

And setup.py to:

```
scripts=['foo/app.py', 'foo/run.py'],
entry_points={
    'console_scripts': [
        'hello-world=run:main'
    ]
}
```

After installing using pip, `app.py` and `run.py` are being added to /bin which seems to solve the issue.